# Unit Test case of Containers in React

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, redux-mock-store

I am trying to write a test case of a container in React. But I am stuck in the form submit case. I am not able to pass actions in my component. Here is my container.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty'

import { getLoggedInUser } from '../../api/user.api'

const Authenticate = (props, { actions, history, user }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('shubhra.vyas')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('1234')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(user)) {
      history.push('/dashboard')
    }
  }, [user])

  let login = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    actions.getLoggedInUser({ username, password })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={login}>
        <div>
          <TextField
            id='userName'
            label='User Name'
            type='text'
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <TextField
            id='password'
            label='Password'
            type='password'
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <Button variant='contained' type='submit' color='primary'>
          Login
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.user
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(
      {
        getLoggedInUser,
      },
      dispatch,
    ),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Authenticate)
```

I am using the enzyme, redux-thunk, redux-mock-store for testing.

Your response would be highly appreciated. It has taken a lot of time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does it mean "not able to pass actions"? how did you try passing them? did you wrap component with `<Provider store={mockedStore}>`?

Comment: I can pass redux state using below

`import thunk from 'redux-thunk'`
`import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk])

let wrapper, store
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({
      user: { firstName: 'Joe' },
    })
    wrapper = shallow(
      <Authenticate store={store} />,
    )
  })`

Comment: Same way, how to pass actions in container ?

Comment: Include dependent files for more clarity

Comment: No dependent files. The above one is the actual component & the snippet in comment is its test file.